# How to restart a freezing windows 8 on macbook pro

Tags: windows-8, freeze, macbook-pro

My windows 8 on macbook pro has freezed and I need to restart or shutdown but I don't know how, is there any keyboard shortcut for this? I tried searching for this issue all what I found was people talking about the random freezes that occur for windows 8 on macbook pro and why does the freeze occurs and how to overcome this freeze by installing or updating drivers or enabling something through the cmd but nothing explains how to get out first from this freeze in order to apply the suggested solutions for overcoming future freezes.
This is the first freeze I got since I installed windows 8 64-bit on my macbook 2 weeks ago and it has been freezing since 1 hr and 15 min and no response. I unplugged the power, it doesn't go sleep it just reduces the screen brightness but it's still freezing.

Any help please.

Comment: Are you using the current version of Boot Camp? If Windows is freezing every hour then there is likely a scheduled task you have created. I would use a restore point to try a configuration from before 2 weeks ago.  **Just hold the power button to force a hard reboot.**  If the operating system if frozen a keyboard shortcut is useless.

Comment: Yes am using the current version of boot camp, the latest one. The windows is not freezing every hour, I mentioned it has been freezing since an hour ago, it didn't freeze before ever since the first installation 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reboot maybe as suggested previously, by holding the power button down for roughly 5 odd seconds.

Boot into Win8 but in safe mode and see if you continue to freeze.  If not, then you'll have to eliminate software/drivers one by one until you find the problematic.  I'd suggest starting with the network drivers as they caused trouble for me on my macbook pro.